# Fried flour tortilla from scratch cook first or just fry

Tags: mexican-cuisine

I'm working on my chicken flauta recipe skills today, I like to make everything from scratch but all I can find are recipes with store bought tortillas.   Knowing how much better homemade corn tortillas are I'm thinking of trying this with scratch made flour tortillas, stuffing and then frying.   My question is should I first cook the flour tortillas in a pan, then fill and fry?  Or fill and fry with the raw dough after pressing it?

Comment: Store bought tortillas are at least partially cooked.

Comment: This looks like it would be a good chance to try both methods, do half with the raw dough and half with the cooked to see which one provides the best results.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://thecafesucrefarine.com/2013/08/best-ever-homemade-flour-tortillas/)... <strike>neither</strike> your first option. You should toast them in a pan without oil.

> After rest period, heat a large pan over medium-high heat. Roll each
>   dough piece into a rough circle, about 6-7 inches in diameter, keep
>   work surface and rolling pin lightly floured. Don’t stack uncooked
>   tortillas on top of each other or they will get soggy.
>
> When pan is very hot, place one dough circle into pan and allow to
>   cook about 1 minute or until bottom surface has a few pale brown
>   spots. The uncooked surface will begin to show a few little bubbles.
>   If tortilla is browning too fast, reduced heat a bit. If it’s taking
>   longer than a minute to see a few pale golden brown spots on underside
>   of tortillas, increase heat a bit. Flip to other side and cook for
>   about 30 seconds. You want the tortilla to be soft but have a few
>   small pale golden brown spots on surface. Remove from pan with tongs
>   and stack in a covered container or zippered bag till all tortillas
>   are cooked. This will keep them soft and pliable.

You can view the complete recipe following the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I would fry the raw dough, like an empanada. That way you can seal in the filling by crimping the dough.